# IMAP: Query to get all the reply email and get the Id of parent email

Tags: c#, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am writing an application to get important emails from separate account and merge it into in a common place.

I want to know all the emails for which we got the replies and want to read those replied emails along with parent email Message Id.

I have simple query on date.

```
var query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(from)
                        .And(SearchQuery.DeliveredBefore(to))
```

And loop through every email and save them in database. But I want to group emails by emails and their replies

Comment: Are these emails stored in database? Did you try to write and query? Can you share it here? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Yes I store them in database. I want to segregate between replies and first email. @ChetanRanpariya Question edited with query

Comment: The first Emails will not have parentid. So you need to get all the emails which has parentid null.

Comment: IMAP doesn't show anything like ParentId

Comment: You want to query from database or from IMAP?

Comment: This is called threading the email, there are [many older questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bimap%5D+threading) that you might look through.

Comment: Could you please provide a link of the library you're currently using?

Comment: MimeKit and MailKit. Nuget packages are available